# How to calculate percentage of order items in all ordersin Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having difficulties with calculating how much of an item is present in all order portfolios in percentage?
Items are toys that people usually buy: bear, rabbit, moose, dog, horse, cat, mouse, pig, chicken, eagle, raccoon, dolphin, shark, and whale.

I have an order_portfolio_id which represents the person buying the toys, and I have columns position_X where X is the number of position of the item ordered, with total of 8 positions. Person ordering the toys will never buy the same toy twice, so the items never repeat in one portfolio/row. Please note my original dataframe contains NaN, so I included them here as well.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from numpy import nan
>>> 
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'order_portfolio_num': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
...                     'order_position_1':['dog', 'horse', 'cat','shark', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'cat'],
...                     'order_position_2':['mouse', 'bear', 'dog', 'dolphin', 'cat', 'bear', 'eagle', 'shark'],
...                     'order_position_3':['bear', 'dog', 'raccoon', 'dog', 'whale', 'mouse', 'cat', 'moose'],
...                     'order_position_4':['dolphin', 'cat', 'chicken', nan, 'horse', 'pig', 'dog', 'chicken'],
...                     'order_position_5':['pig', 'chicken', 'eagle', nan, 'bear', 'raccoon', 'whale', nan], 
...                     'order_position_6':[nan, 'whale', nan, nan, 'eagle', 'moose', nan, nan],
...                     'order_position_7':[nan, 'dolphin', nan, nan, nan, 'chicken', nan, nan]})
>>> 
>>> data
   order_portfolio_num order_position_1 order_position_2 order_position_3 order_position_4 order_position_5 order_position_6 order_position_7
0                    1              dog            mouse             bear          dolphin              pig              NaN              NaN
1                    2            horse             bear              dog              cat          chicken            whale          dolphin
2                    3              cat              dog          raccoon          chicken            eagle              NaN              NaN
3                    4            shark          dolphin              dog              NaN              NaN              NaN              NaN
4                    5              dog              cat            whale            horse             bear            eagle              NaN
5                    6           rabbit             bear            mouse              pig          raccoon            moose          chicken
6                    7           rabbit            eagle              cat              dog            whale              NaN              NaN
7                    8              cat            shark            moose          chicken              NaN              NaN              NaN
```

I would like to calculate top 5 most common toys ordered across all portfolios, in percentage. For example, if I have 10 order_portfolios, and the toy bear is present in 4 of them, the bear toy will than have a value of 40%. My goal is to have something that looks like this:

```
toy      percent
dog        60%
cat        48%
mouse      36%
bear       28%
shark      19%
```

I tried to sum across all toys in the dataframe, but i got the number of occurrences of all toys in all portfolios, and I am unsure exactly how to calculate the percentage from that (which value represents the 100% value?), and if it's even that I am looking for as it will give me percentage of occurrences of all toys, and not portfolios. So I am unsure how to proceed. This is what I tried:

```
>>> cols = ['order_position_1', 'order_position_2', 'order_position_3', 'order_position_4',
...        'order_position_5', 'order_position_6', 'order_position_7'] 
>>> 
>>> position_values = data[cols].melt().groupby('value').size().reset_index(name='count')
>>> 
>>> position_values.sort_values(by = 'count', ascending = False)
      value  count
3       dog      6
1       cat      5
0      bear      4
2   chicken      4
4   dolphin      3
5     eagle      3
13    whale      3
6     horse      2
7     moose      2
8     mouse      2
9       pig      2
10   rabbit      2
11  raccoon      2
12    shark      2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and divide by original number of rows:

```
df = data.melt('order_portfolio_num')['value'].value_counts().div(len(data)).mul(100).head()
print (df)
dog        75.0
cat        62.5
bear       50.0
chicken    50.0
dolphin    37.5
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the general idea:

1. First get the name of all toys
2. Check, for every toy, if it is in a row and store that count
3. Get the frecuency

```
unique_values = df.drop(columns = "order_portfolio_num").stack().unique()
count = pd.Series([(df == x).any(1).sum() for x in unique_values], unique_values)
frec = count / df["order_portfolio_num"].size() * 100

print(frec.head())
dog        75.0
mouse      25.0
bear       50.0
dolphin    37.5
pig        25.0
```

---

**Documentation**

- [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- [`pandas.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html)
- [`pandas.Series.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.size.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)
- [`pandas.Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html)
- [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

devide each value  by the number of order portfolios (N)

```
position_values['percent']=position_values['count']/data['order_portfolio_num'].count()
```

and then sort and head